# How to get .q extension recognised in github

Tags: github, kdb

I am not sure if it's possible , i want to get `.q` file extension recognized by GitHub so that :

1. GitHub can highlight the keywords of q language  (by providing the full list of keywords somehow ; e.g. `sum,diff,avg`) while viewing the files in the repo ; currently the files are treated as simple text.
2. Popular repositories page show the language `q` and assign a colored dot (like in case of python)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are currently several pull requests on the github [linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) repo for recognising `.q` files. Unfortunately it seems that everytime a PR gains traction another comes along and steals the limelight, in addition to some other issues.

In short, if you want `.q` files recognised you'd have to get one of those PRs approved.

**Update**

Support for q was added on 2nd May 2018. See relevant [PR](https://github.com/github/linguist/pull/4058).

Comment: This appears to be the closest to the top but its stagnated: https://github.com/github/linguist/pull/3820

Comment: I think [PR 4058](https://github.com/github/linguist/pull/4058) probably has the best chance at this stage, only because it is most fresh.